# Adding LIMIT keyword causes an error in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Consider the code below. It produces an error on line 5.

```sql
SELECT
  usertype,
  CONCAT(start_station_name,"to",end_station_name) AS route,
  COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
  ROUND(AVG(CAST(tripduration as int64)/60,2) AS duration
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
GROUP BY start_station_name, end_station_num, usetype
ORDER BY num_trips DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Answer (score 0):

In line 5 there are three "(" and only two ")" parentheses.